# Eloquent pivot table of 3 join to another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following models / tables setup in my Laravel application;

**users**
        id
        profile_id

**profiles**
        id
        description

**modules**
        id
        description

**submodules**
        id
        description
        module_id

**profile_permission**
        id
        profile_id
        submodule_id
        permission_id

A user has one profile
A module has many submodules
A submodule has many permissions

I am still trying to find my out using eloquent.  How can I get an array in the format for the profile_id 1?:
 [module.id][submodule.id][permission.id]

An example output
[1][10][1]
[1][10][2]
[1][10][3]

Answer (score 0):

You can define `hasMany` relationship between `Profile` model and `ProfilePermission` like this

Profile model

```
public function profilePermissions(){
    return $this->hasMany(ProfilePermission::class, 'profile_id');
}
```

Now you can fetch it like this

```
$profile = Profile::with('profilePermissions')->find(1);
foreach($profile->profilePermissions as $pp){
   echo $pp->profile_id.'-'. $pp->submodule_id .'-'. $pp->permission_id
}
```

**Note:** If you define `belongsTo` relation in `ProfilePermission` model for each foreign key `profile_id`, `submodule_id` and `permission_id` then you can access its model too.

Comment: Can I link the submodule_id column in the profile_permission pivot table to the modules table and query the module.id? Thanks.

Comment: do you have ManyToMany relation between profile and permission ? If yes then you can create a ProfilePermession model extending Pivot and then add belongsTo relation to submodule. And submodule has belongsTo relation to Module. So finally you got it

Comment: but when you add any relation in Model that extending Pivot then you can’t load these relation with eager load . Thats why when you have more than 2 foreign key then better go with hasMany relation

Comment: Thanks a lot @rkj, Yes, profile and permission have ManyToMany relation.

Comment: then follow my comments, but i recommend to use `hasMany` if more than 2 foreign key in pivot table